# Laravel 5 Eloquent "with" method: joining multiple tables and filter columns in joined tables

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

I store users and user profiles in two separate tables where Users table has username and email column, UserProfile table has name and employee_no column.

User.php

```
public function userProfile()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Utility\UserProfile', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

UserProfile.php

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Utility\User', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

I'm using with method to load profile information with users. 
Following code loads list of users with profile and can filter username column and email column.

UserManagementController.php

```
public function getUserProfile(){
    $users = User::with('UserProfile')
            ->where('username', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('q').'%')
            ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('q').'%')
            ->paginate(5);


    return view('user_profile',compact('users'));
}
```

But I cannot filter name and employee_no field in UserProfile table as I cannot access these fields.
So what is Eloquent's way of  joining  multiple tables and filter columns in joined tables.

Answer (score 2):

```
public function getUserProfile(){
$users = User::join('UserProfile', 'users.id', '=', 'UserProfile.user_id')
        ->where('username', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('q').'%')
        ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('q').'%')
        ->orWhere('UserProfile.employee_id', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('q').'%')
        ->orWhere('UserProfile.name', 'LIKE', '%'.Input::get('q').'%')
        ->paginate(5);


return view('user_profile',compact('users'));
```

}

Using join method in Larvel Query Builder solved the problem